# What's the name for the bugs known on the release

Tags: terminology

Many of us have that experience where you had to release a product that you know has the bugs in it while the development. The situation being rushed deadlines, the severity of the bug...

What do you call them?

Could just call them "known bugs". But this particular term I'm looking for puts emphasis on the bugs that they're found before the release of the product/version, and the time was short to investigate/solve.

Comment: bad quality ?  known bugs ?  customer disrespect ? weird feature ?

Comment: They're "Features".   :)

Comment: Basically, they are issues.

Answer (score 19):

Often, software is released with a document called “Release Notes”, and there may be a section called “Known Issues” that usually outlines small issues to be aware of and how to mitigate their impact if necessary.

Here’s an example of the release notes from a commercial software product:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/10.0/rn/fusion-100-release-notes.html